# What is the ssh option similar to `telnet -8` to deal with encoding issues

Tags: ssh, telnet

When I use telnet to connect a bbs site with

```
luit -encoding gbk telnet bdwm.net
```

with UTF8 encoding in locale in Mac Iterm2, the display is fine, but I cannot input Chinese. So I use

```
luit -encoding gbk telnet -8 bdwm.net
```

Everything is fine.

The problem is there is no option like `-8` for `ssh`. So if I connect the site with `ssh`, I cannot input Chinese again.

So my question is:

- Is there a option for `ssh` to solve the input problem?

Answer (score 0):

SSH should not have encoding issues, if both TTY run with the same TTY modes (should be ensured by protocol) and support UTF8. If one of them does not support some of the flags then it is a problem of the respective end.

This was recently [solved](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-bugs/2015-October/015533.html) in the Linux and openssh-7.3. I am not sure how is this handled in your Macs.